# Are companies supposed to send everyone to training courses?

Tags: training

People are being laid off and I'm a bit worried. I have been with the same company for over 20 years, but they refuse to train us properly. This has been brought up in every review by everybody it affects.

All we are getting is a quick 5 minutes then expected to learn as you go. The management are allowed to training courses, so we have to ask them all the time how to do things.

My problem I fear that I am going to be laid off for not being qualified for my own job as I'm over 20 years behind in training. I have been doing the older work so couldn't get another job as I have dated skills.

Is it OK for a company to keep you behind in training, are they supposed to train all of us or just 1 employee and give in-house training?

Comment: Roughly what is your job?  What sort of training do you need?  Also, what do you mean by "this has been brought up in every review by every body it affects"?  That every employee complains in their performance reviews?  That some outside body is auditing your training?

Comment: +1 it's up to the company to decide how much training they want to give weighing the pros and cons of that strategy. If you feel like you're aren't growing in your role and your older skills are dated, I would pick up the newer skills on your own.

Comment: The question itself is clear, but the entire situation itself is really foggy.

Comment: Are you talking about a job where you're legally required to hold certain certifications/licences/etc.?

Answer (score 4):

You might not be happy about it but its absolutely okay for a company to train you however they'd like. If the training is not effective, then it hurts the company the most.

Sounds to me like they send a few people to the training, then have them teach you the things that they found important. Sending employees to training can be expensive. This means that the company would rather save the money sending only a couple people, then hope that they can tell you what you need to know.

You've been at this place for a long time, and it sounds like they don't really care to listen to your advice. If you feel your job is jeopardy, then polish up your resume and cover letter and start looking. Depending on your profession, its very possible that you'd get hired BECAUSE you know the old stuff (that younger people are no longer being trained on) and you can use that to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a country tag so it's hard to say exactly what is true for where you are.  In my experience in Canada the only domains where companies are required to offer any training are HR and safety.  The HR training that I've been told is legally mandatory is anti-bullying training.  WHIMIS is required training for anyone using any sort of chemical.  There are specifics in the provincial OH&S act (Canadian equivalent to OSHA) regarding training for specific task.

Unfortunately training to keep skills sharp and current isn't a legal requirement in anyplace I can think of.  If you are unionized it may be a worthwhile discussion with your shop steward/union rep to see if the union covers any training costs.

Answer (score 0):

"Supposed to" ... If you mean, is there some law that companies must provide training, not in the United States. I don't know about other countries. It would be a difficult law to enforce, because you'd have to ask, What sort of training? Which employees? It would surely be a waste of everyone's time to have a law saying that an employee who runs a drill press must have training in Java programming or that an employee who writes Java programs must have training in use of a drill press. Etc.

If you mean, is it customary, do most companies do this? Again, in the US only sporadically. I can't speak for other countries. Most companies I've worked for never provided any training. I recall one company that had extensive training for many employees, constantly bringing in teachers or sending people to classes, but that was the exception.

If you mean, Would it be a good idea? Probably so.

Realistically, lots of people don't want to learn new things. They're happy doing what they're doing and don't want to have to learn something new. When companies I've worked for have offered training, many employees didn't want to go, and found excuses to miss the classes.

Nothing is stopping you from learning new things on your own. Especially in the Internet age, you can get all sorts of material on line.

Answer (score 0):

No, employers don't have to send anyone to training. If you've been around for 20 years, you've certainly seen this. Sadly, the current fashion is to not train people at all but rather "require" that they are already trained upon hiring and then drop them in like a cog to get working. If they become obsolete, just lay-off the obsolete and hire new folks who are already trained. I don't think it's anything personal, it's just that employers are increasingly choosing to drop 100% of any responsibility for the stewardship of the careers of their workers.

The best thing an employee who feels they're getting obsolete can do is to take responsibility for their own training. If your trade has certifications that are valuable, go and get them. If there's some coursework, workshops or conferences that are useful to your career, just go.

Though it would be nice to get funding from your employer, that isn't necessary, nor do you need their permission. It is reasonable to ask for time off to get training, but again, just take PTO or do it on your own time if they refuse. Some training providers do provide relief for self-funded folks, so keep that in mind. Also, self-directed training or training with an interest group (who may or may not be at work) is totally possible.

Once you've trained, however, you'll need to somehow exercise those skills at your current work or find other work that will allow you to practice. No one will believe you actually have these new skills unless you use them at work.